# Notepad++ How to delete everything before the first Colon

Tags: notepad++

Example Text:

```
test3:orange;mango
test324:cherry;peach
test35:apple;pear
```

I want to get delete the 'test' part on every line.

I know there is an expression for deleting everything before the first colon.

Answer (score 11):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^:]+`   or `^[^:]+:` if you want to remove also the colon
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
  [^:]+ : 1 or more any character that is not a colon
  :     : a colon (only if you want to remove it)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
:orange;mango
:cherry;peach
:apple;pear
```

OR

```
orange;mango
cherry;peach
apple;pear
```

Comment: Very useful RegEx. Thank you, Toto!

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Find and Replace Dialogue" (Ctrl + H assuming Windows) and enable the `Regualar Expression` search mode. The following regular expression in the search box will highlight "test" followed by any text up to and including the colon:

`^(test).*:`

You can leave the "Replace With" box empty and click "Replace All" to simply delete all instances in a file, or enter a colon in the "Replace With" box to keep the colon.

See the image below for reference

[image]

You can learn more about Regular Expressions from Microsoft's [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: this deletes everything up to the *last* colon since regex search is aggressive by default, so it won't work if the line has multiple colons